# transformer to socket not working

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter, transformer-model

Its driving me nuts trying days to grind this problem.

I am writing a java server to work with an android application. They communicate text string and xml.

Currently simple socket communication seems fine, however it breaks down when I tried to use transformer instead of simple println.

Server code as below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


public class javamultithreadedserver implements Runnable {
Socket csocket; 
static int listenport = 6021;
public static final String endOfCom = "endofcom";
String connectionname;

public javamultithreadedserver(Socket csocket, String connectionname) {
    this.csocket = csocket;
    this.connectionname = connectionname;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int listentoport = 0;
    //System.out.println(args.length);
    if (args.length == 1){
        listentoport = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } else{
        listentoport = listenport;
    }
    ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(listentoport);
    System.out.println("Listening at port " + listentoport);
    while (true) {
         Socket sock = ssock.accept();
         System.out.println("Connected. from: " + sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + sock.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " port: " + sock.getPort() + " " + sock.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName());
         new Thread(new javamultithreadedserver(sock, sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + sock.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " " + sock.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName())).start();
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
      try {
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(), true);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csocket.getInputStream()));
          PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream (csocket.getOutputStream(), true);

          String inputLine, outputLine;

          System.out.println(connectionname + ": listening for query information.");
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(connectionname + ": " + inputLine);
              //out.write("received something");
              DBQuery q = new DBQuery(inputLine + DBQuery.regexsplit + "connectionname" + DBQuery.regexsplit + connectionname);
              DOMSource dmsource = q.returns();

              ***//StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out); //debug***
              StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(pstream);
              TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
              Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
              Thread.sleep(100);
              ***transformer.transform(dmsource, consoleResult);***

              //out.println("println this is a testprogram"); // client receive ok

              pstream.flush();
              System.out.println(connectionname + ": reply sent.");

              if (inputLine == endOfCom){
                  System.out.println(connectionname + ": is satisfied and terminated communication.");
                  break;
              }
          }           
          pstream.close();
          csocket.close();
       }catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }        
}
}
```

And the android client code as below:

```
public void run() {
if (barcode.length() > 0) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        out.write(barcode + ENDL);
        if(out.checkError()){
            showToUI("PrintWriter had error");
        } else {
            showToUI("Query sent");
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try{
                if (**(serverResponse = in.readLine()) != null**) {
                    if(serverResponse == endOfCom){
                        Log.i("communicated all data", "bye");
                        out.write(endOfCom + ENDL);
                        break;
                    } else{
                    }
                    Log.i("server says", serverResponse);
                }
                //Log.i("server says", (serverResponse == null? "null" :serverResponse ));
            }catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
                showToUI(barcode + ": Server did not respond in time");
                if (i++ > 2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (final UnknownHostException e1) {
        showToUI(e1.toString());
    } catch (final IOException e1) {
        showToUI(e1.toString());
    } finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            showToUI(e.toString());
        }
    }
}else{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter something in barcode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have tested that the xml result returned was ok, if the Stream Result was set to `System.out` instead of the PrintStream `pstream`, everything prints perfectly to the console.

However with or without `pstream.flush()`, client received no response at `(serverResponse = in.readLine()) != null`.

Also the PrintWriter `out` which was based on the same Socket `socket` of `pstream` successfully gave feedback to the client. When `out.println("println this is a testprogram");` was called, the client received log at the `Log.i("server says", serverResponse);` line OK.

One thing to note is that the reply is usually quite long, can be up to 65536 characters or even more, I do not know if that has any implication, I have tried to create a Buffered reader on the android app larger than the replying xml, it still did not work. The machines are communicating on local network, java server program is running on a different machine from the android emulator.

Any help is appreciated, this had been going on for days and nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` won't return null until the peer closes the connection. And when it does return null, you need to break out of the loop. And don't compare string s with ==.

Comment: Thanks EJP, the close really did return.
However it was stated in the Android Developer reference that 

public String readLine ()
Returns the next line of text available from this reader. 

I think the main problem is, currently it is not returning anything until peer closes, which was not stated in the reference.

I will break out of the loop, the current version is revised so many times, I am focusing on getting return, no longer the program flow.

Also I am unsure if I shall use == or .equals(), .equals() gives error when it returns null, maybe .equals(String(null)).

Comment: The problem has now been worked around by calling pstream.println("") after transformer.transform(dmsource, consoleResult), the client is now picking up respond from server in the readline(), though I have no clue what that should be, perhaps transformer.transform() does not produce the ending newline character. Thankyou EJP for the initial clue.